# Show rows of a file which have a regular expression more than 'n' number of times

Tags: linux, unix, awk, grep

I have file- abc.txt, in below format-

```
a:,b:,c:,d:,e:,f:,g:
a:0;b:,c:3,d:,e:,f:,g:1
a:9,b:8,c:6,d:5,e:2,f:,g:
a:0;b:,c:2,d:1,e:,f:,g:
```

Now in unix, I want to get only those rows where this regular expression `:[0-9]` (colon followed by any number) exists more than 2 times. 
Or in other words show rows where at least 3 attributes have numerical values present.

Output should be only 2nd and 3rd row

```
a:0;b:,c:3,d:,e:,f:,g:1
a:9,b:8,c:6,d:5,e:2,f:,g:
```

Comment: why not `a:0;b:,c:2,d:1,e:,f:,g` is a valid row ?

Answer (score 1):

With basic `grep`:

```
grep '\(:[[:digit:]].*\)\{3,\}' file
```

`:[[:digit:]].*` matches a colon followed by a digit and zero or more arbitrary characters. This expressions is put into a sub pattern: `\(...\)`. The expression `\{3,\}` means that the previous expression has to occur 3 or more times.

With extended posix regular expressions this can be written a little simpler, without the need to escape `(` and `{`:

```
grep -E '(:[[:digit:]].*){3,}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -F':[0-9]' 'NF>3' file
a:0;b:,c:3,d:,e:,f:,g:1
a:9,b:8,c:6,d:5,e:2,f:,g:
a:0;b:,c:2,d:1,e:,f:,g:
```

Answer (score -1):

```
perl -nE '/:[0-9](?{$count++})(?!)/; print if $count > 2; $count=0' input
```

Answer (score -2):

`perl -ne 'print if /(.*?\:\d.*?){2,}/' yourfile`

This matches rows having character:number twice or more times.

https://regex101.com/r/tRWtbY/1

Comment: you need to use posix regular expressions when working with grep or awk. GNU grep can use perl regular expressions when `-P` is used, but that's not posix

Comment: A regexp that matches a string in some online tool is just that - a regexp that matches a string in some online tool. It's not adequate and is rarely of any use at all when trying to develop functionality for some command line tool that may include the use of a regexp